# MVC Razor - DropDownListFor - Error on Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post, ienumerable, dropdownlistfor

i'm trying to associate the selected Value to a a parameter defined in Model but now i have the error: "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items"

In Model i have:

```
public class ObjectivesModel
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [Display(Name = "AssociatedGoal")]
    public int AssociatedGoal { get; set; }
```

}

In Controler i create the list

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult NewObjective()
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> example = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "ola1", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "ola2", Value = "2" }
        };

        ViewBag.GoalsToAssociate = example;

        return View();
    }
```

And Finally in View I have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){

             <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(o => o.AssociatedGoal)</div>
            <div class="editor-DropDownList">@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.AssociatedGoal, new SelectList(@ViewBag.GoalsToAssociate, "Value", "Text"), "--Select Goal--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.AssociatedGoal)

            </div>
```

So the error occurs when i submit the form..
I have any special code yet on post version of controler

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewObjective(Models.ObjectivesModel objective)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you get this error while posting this form. Maybe you don't pass the `SelectList` to the `View` in your `[HttpPost]` version of the `Action`?

**Edit:**

In response to your edit: You should also include the `SelectList` code in the `[HttpPost]` version.

Comment: But when i select an elemento from the DropDownListFor, it will be saved on AssociatedGoal presented in Model righ ?
So, i pass the whole model to [HttpPost], that contains the values getted from view.. Why i should include the SelectList ??

Comment: I tried it now, and it works! I didnt know that it was necessary send elements to DropDownList on HttpPost too.
Thanks a lot :)